# pandas: remove rows if condition is met

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like:

```
date                airport_id  plane_type    runway
2020-01-01            11        333           3
2020-01-01            11        222           3
2020-01-02            11        333           3
2020-01-02            11        222           3
2020-01-03            11        333           3
2020-01-04            11        222           3
2020-01-01            12        222           3
2020-01-01            12        345           4
```

On a given date, no two types of plane (`plane_type`) can be present if they have a same `runway`, removing the row with bigger `plane_type`

Expected output:

```
date                airport_id  plane_type    runway
2020-01-01            11        222           3
2020-01-02            11        222           3
2020-01-03            11        333           3
2020-01-04            11        222           3
2020-01-01            12        222           3
2020-01-01            12        345           4
```

Any help would be very much appreciated! Thank you

Comment: How can the 2nd and 3rd rows of the result coexist under your condition?

Comment: `df.groupby(['date', 'airport_id', 'runway']).max()` I think this should work?

Comment: @Gulzar look at the dates, they are different

Comment: @noah apologies for a typo, I wish to keep the smaller values and drop the max ones

Comment: @SergedeGossondeVarennes they can be, since the `runway` is different

Comment: @Alexander it says removing the row with *bigger* plane_type

Comment: `df.groupby(['date', 'airport_id', 'runway']).min()` then if you want the smaller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you want to take the smallest `plane_type` for a given `date`, `airport_id` and `plane_type`.  You could do that via a `groupby` statement as follows:

```
result = (
    df.groupby(['date', 'airport_id', 'runway'], as_index=False)['plane_type'].min()
   .sort_values(['airport_id', 'runway'])
)
>>> result
         date  airport_id  runway  plane_type
0  2020-01-01          11       3         222
3  2020-01-02          11       3         222
4  2020-01-03          11       3         333
5  2020-01-04          11       3         222
1  2020-01-01          12       3         222
2  2020-01-01          12       4         345
```

You can then merge additional columns (e.g. `city` and `country`) back to this result, assuming that the values are unique for the given merge key.

```
result.merge(df, on=['date', 'airport_id', 'runway', 'plane_type'])
```

Comment: There are two other columns in the original `df` like `city` and `country` (independent of what we're doing but the need to be present) I lose them when I do this. Should I put them in the groupby as well?

Comment: Where? in the end?

Comment: Could you please have it edited i the answer? the syntax seems to go off

Comment: Then the problem is poorly specified.

Answer (score 0):

From your expected output I see that there should be added
a requirement concerning the *airport_id*:

- no two types of plane...,
- in any given *airport_id* (this is the part to add),
- if they have a same *runway*.

To generate this result, run:

```
result = df.groupby(['date', 'airport_id', 'runway'], as_index=False,
    sort=False).apply(lambda grp: grp[grp.plane_type == grp.plane_type.min()])\
    .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

The result is:

```
        date  airport_id  plane_type  runway
1 2020-01-01          11         222       3
3 2020-01-02          11         222       3
4 2020-01-03          11         333       3
5 2020-01-04          11         222       3
6 2020-01-01          12         222       3
7 2020-01-01          12         345       4
```

Try also another concept, i.e.:

- first set the grouping columns as the index,
- then *groupby*,
- and the last point - change the index columns back to "normal" columns.

The code to do it is:

```
result = df.set_index(['date', 'airport_id', 'runway'])\
    .groupby(['date', 'airport_id', 'runway'], as_index=False)\
    .apply(lambda grp: grp[grp.plane_type == grp.plane_type.min()])\
    .reset_index(level=[1,2,3])
```

Access by the index should be considerably faster, so if the execution
speed is the problem, this may be a better approach.

Comment: You missed the last point, Keep only the `minimum` plane_type hence we would not be getting `333` but `222` for 2020-01-01 in airport 11

Comment: Also I have two other columns `city` and `country` should I put them in the groupby? or a separate join?

Comment: PS. on a bigger dataset this is taking very long time!

Comment: I think that *airport_id* in a unique way defines the airport, so neither *country* nor *city* is needed in grouping.